# UISwitch control shifted in iPad 4.3 Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

I use the UISwitch control under iPad 5.0 and everything works fine. But if I run the app under iPad 4.3 that control shifted to the left.

[image]

In this sample both controls have the same autosizing mask and content mode.
Deployment Target: 4.3
Base SDK 5.0

Somebody can explain my problem.

Comment: can you add how and when this is added to your app and also what are the different settings of your UISwitch.

Comment: For this sample I added the controls from Interface Builder and not touch any settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not pretty... both UISwitch don't have the same width.
I use to this code to try something :

```
CGRect aRect = self.mySwitch.frame;
aRect.origin.x = 20;
aRect.origin.y = 20;
self.mySwitch.frame = aRect;
```

And that give me the right placement in both simulator.
So This explain, but how to fixe this without that ugly piece of code.

---

This are the values of center and origin I got back in the NSLog.

```
ipad iOS 5
LOG: Center of sw1 x == 60 : y == 33.50
LOG: Origin of sw1 x == 20 : y == 20.00
ipad iOS 4.3
LOG: Center of sw1 x == 52 : y == 33.50
LOG: Origin of sw1 x ==  5 : y == 20.00
```

Maybe the code from Apple is written so an App that was developed before iOS 5 would have it's switch display correctly, but the inverse is not true...
I hope to see a better explanation.

Comment: Yes, I found that different width of the control in iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0. But why is not backwards compatible? And I have not found that someone else has discussed this issue.

Comment: I have this issue too. I have no idea why the switches are right-aligned, even when I have set them to fixed top and left in the xib.